# How to represent integers using Egyptian fractions?

Tags: summation, number-theory

Let $N(n)$ be a set of integers, which can be presented using first $n$ Egyptian fractions:

$$
N(n):=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}:\ \ m=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\epsilon_i}{i},\ \epsilon_i=0\ \text{or}\ 1\}
$$

I want to write a code in **Mathematica** that gives $N(n)$, but I think `A[e,n]` does not define what I need above: for example

```
A[e_,n_]:=Sum[e/i,{e,0,1},{i,1,n}];
n=1000;    
Sum[If[IntegerQ[A[e,n]]==True,m,0],{m,1,10}]
```

Thanks.

P.S. example

\begin{align}
0=&0\\
1=&1\\
2=&1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac04+\frac05+\frac16
\end{align}
therefore $N(6)=\{0,1,2\}$

Comment: `A[e,n]` does not depend on `e`. So you can use `A[n_]:=...` Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Your `A` function takes `e == 0` and runs through all the `i`-values, and then takes  `e == 1` and runs through all the `i`-values, giving `0/1 + 0/2 + ... + 0/n + 1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n`. Try `Table[{e, i}, {e, 0, 1}, {i, 1, 6}]` to see what the indices are doing.

Comment: Doesn't N(n) always contain 0?  For example, for N(6), 0 = 0/1 + 0/2 + 0/3 + 0/4 + 0/5 + 0/6.

Comment: A solution that scales (very, very) poorly is `Union[Select[Total /@ Subsets[1/Range[6]], IntegerQ]]` (for n=6, for example).

Comment: You can brute force it for $n \lesssim 25$. Will that work, or are you really interested in $n=1000$?

Comment: I changed the title to make the question to be more attractive. I hope, you don't mind.

Comment: @evanb, thanks, I corrected. Also  I like to have representation for each of them in *output* as you see in P.S.

Comment: Straight-forward method using `Solve` (and not suffering from exponential memory usage) would be something like this: `n0 /. (With[{n = 50}, 
    Solve[{Sum[a[i]/i, {i, n}] == n0, 
      Array[a, n] \[Element] Cuboid[ConstantArray[0, n]]}, {n0}, 
     Integers]] /. ConditionalExpression[v_, ___] :> v) (* {0, 1, 2, 3} *)` ... this doesn't solve the exponential time complexity, though.

Comment: This problem is essentially the same as computing the [OEIS sequence  A101877](http://oeis.org/A101877). With a little bit of cleverness one can search the values up to at least 300 (which would correspond with $N(300)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$), just by using straight-forward `Solve` and constraints on the problem size based on solutions already found. Going up to the sum corresponding to 6 (at 469) might be infeasible using this method (probably takes at least several days of computing time, possibly a lot more).

Answer (score 4):

This solution acquires answers for couple hundred first values of $N$ - probably not much further in a reasonable amount of time. Much more efficient - and more explicit - code for finding larger values can be found in a link from [OEIS A101877](http://oeis.org/A101877).

This pair of functions computes both $N$ and its companion function which returns a list of new integer solutions (value and contributing integers in sum of fractions) for any $N$. The construct is recursive, always searching only for solutions for sums which haven't been seen for lower values.

```
ClearAll[n, sn];
n[0] = {0};
n[x_] := n[x] = Union[n[x - 1], sn[x][[All, 1]]];
sn[0] = {{0, {}}};
sn[x_] := sn[x] = With[{r = Array[c, x]},
    {a /. #, Flatten@Position[r /. #, 1]} & /@
     Solve[Sum[c[i]/i, {i, x}] == a && c[x] == 1 && 
       Unequal[a, Sequence @@ n[x - 1]] && 
       And @@ (0 <= # <= 1 & /@ r), Append[r, a], Integers]];
```

Even to reach 5 it can take quite a while, over five hours of CPU time - but this  is dramatically more efficient than exhaustive search, still:

```
Timing@n[184]
```

> {19020.6, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

At the same time this call saves solutions for minimum-$N$ integer solutions, for instance:

```
Grid[DeleteCases[Table[sn[i], {i, 0, 65}], {}][[All, 1]], 
 Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Let indicator variables `e_i` encode a number in binary.  That is let $b=\sum_{i} 2^i e_i$.  Then we can loop over all values of $b$ and decode it into a vector of $e$s:

```
e[n_][b_] := ArrayPad[#, {n - Length[#], 0}] &@IntegerDigits[b, 2]
```

(We need to pass n to indicate how long the vector should be).

Now we can loop over all $2^n$ choices for $b$ and compute the sum by taking the dot product with a vector of $1/i$:

```
allSums[n_] := Map[(1/Range[n]).e[n][#] &, Range[2^n]]
```

and now filter / sort:

```
set[n_] := Union@Select[IntegerQ]@allSums[n]
```

I'm afraid that this will still take $\sim2^{1000}$ steps for $n=1000$, but at least it doesn't have an exponentially large memory requirement like the procedure mentioned in my comment :-)  If you're really interested in $n=1000$ you'll need an algorithm that's better than the "obvious" one.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := Sum[x[[i]]/i,{i,1,Length[x]}]
Select[IntegerQ][f /@ Tuples[{0,1},20]]
```

gives still {0,1,2}, with the  raspberry taking 5 min.